# How to get and identify data from other view into the array in UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

First, I want to build my app like this image.

[image]

This app has a table view.
A table view has several sections.
Each `Section` has different number of cells.
Each `Cell` has different types of accessories as sub-view.

Because of this concept, this table view reuses different `UITableViewCell` sub-classes for each cells.

And I want to let users customize a table view by saving after selecting buttons which indicates `the cells`.

Here's the first step : `TableViewController` code. It works well as I intended.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let foodComponents = [["Apple", "Banana", "Grape", "Pear"], ["Beef", "Pork", "Chicken"], ["Shrimp", "Cod", "Anchovy"]]
    let headerTitles = ["Fruits", "Meats", "Fishes"]

    let cellReuseidentifier = "cell"
    let anotherCellReuseidentifier = "anotherCell"
    // + other identifiers for UITableViewCell subclasses

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(FruitTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseidentifier)
        tableView.register(AnotherFruitTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: anotherCellReuseidentifier)  
        // + other UITableViewCell subclasses
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {      
        return foodComponents.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {        
        return foodComponents.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {            
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseidentifier, for: indexPath) as! FruitTableViewCell
                cell.textLabel?.text = foodComponents[indexPath.row]
                return cell
            } else {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: anotherCellReuseidentifier, for: indexPath) as! AnotherFruitTableViewCell
                cell.textLabel?.text = foodComponents[indexPath.row]
                return cell
            }
        } 
        // an so on...
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if section < headerTitles.count {
            return headerTitles[section]
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

The second step is making another view which contains many `UIButton`s to let users customize themselves by selecting them.

**But the problem is,**

**1. Getting user-selected values into the array in the TableViewController**

**2. Identifying them which the TableViewCell subclass belongs to them.**

The `Array` in the `TableViewController` is the basis for `numberOfSections`, `numberOfRows`, `cellForRow`.
But if users select cells, it means that the array will be changed.
If the array is not fixed, `numberOfSections`, `numberOfRows`, `cellForRow` functions will not be executed. And, if `TableViewCell` subclass for user-selected value is not identified, the cells cannot be made.

How to get and identify data from other view into the array in `UITableViewController`?

Comment: try delegates and protocols [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52417289/how-to-pass-and-identify-data-from-other-view-to-the-array-in-uitableviewcontrol)

Comment: Helpful, but Objective-C codes are not familiar to me. And, the problem is slightly different. My problem is, passing and getting data to view-controller file inside, not to a view directly. Because, I want to execute functions based on the passed data.

Comment: How to pass data between view controllers has been asked and answered _many_ times.

Comment: I read it. But, I want to know 'how to identify passed data' as well. How many datas are passed into array in UITableViewController, What are they, ... etc. Anyone has not answered to this question.